# Laravel one to many model relationship not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, one-to-many

I have a `Booking` model which can have many `Service`'s.

I have defined the relationship in the Booking model like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Service;

class Booking extends Model
{
    
    /**
     * Get the services for the booking.
     */
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Service');
    }
}
```

Then in my `BookingController` I try to get all the services for the current booking like this:

```
    public function create()
    {       
        $services = Booking::find(1)->services;
        return view('bookings.create');
    }
```

I keep getting the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The foreign key relation is all set up fine. I have a `booking_id` column in the `services` table which references `id` on the `bookings` table.

Comment: have u imported the Booking class and you are sure you have records in your database

Comment: `find` can return `null`. Does a Booking with `id=1` exist?

Comment: @lagbox Ah, I think that was the issue. There was no Booking with id=1. I tried it with a booking id that existed and it worked. If you write this as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case the issue is probably that Eloquent can't find a Booking with `id == 1`.

`Booking::find(1);` is going to query on the primary key for Booking for `1`. If it is not found it will return `null`. Trying to use that `null` as an object is giving the "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

Answer (score 0):

If your keys are not the ones generated by the laravel models you can try to specify them:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Service', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function create()
    {       
        $services = Booking::find(1)->services;
        return view('bookings.create');
    }
```

By seeing your above code: Ensure that you have record with id 1..if it is , check your primary and foreign key .